# Two questions about MLE

Tags: maximum-likelihood

$$f(x)=\alpha\beta x^{\beta-1}e^{-\alpha x^{\beta}}$$

[image]

1) How do we know that n must be multiplied by both alpha and beta only after we take the log, why don't we simply multiply by n in the original function and then take the log?
2) In the derivative with respect to $\beta$, why do we have a log in the function (after the minus sign)? Where does this come from?

Comment: with (1) I have no idea what you're even asking - e.g. $n$ isn't multiplied by $\alpha$; with (2), what's after the minus sign is an $\alpha$. Are you just asking where the $\log x_i$ comes from? The central problem simply sounds like you're unfamiliar with the mechanics of taking derivatives --- e.g. can you say what $\frac{d}{dx} a^x$ is? If that's the case, it would be a problem better dealt with on math.stackexchange.com; failing that, at least proofread and edit your question carefully to be clear about what you're saying. Can you write $L$ and hence $\log L$ down before simplifying it?

Comment: If this is homework, please add the homework tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given some data $x_i$, $i=1,\ldots,n$, drawn independently from the given density gives a likelihood of

$$L=\prod_{i=1}^{n}f(x_i)=\prod_{i=1}^{n}\alpha\beta x_i^{\beta-1}e^{-\alpha x_i^\beta}$$

The likelihood can be rewritten as $$L=\alpha^n\beta^n\left(\prod_{i=1}^{n}x_i\right)^{\beta-1}e^{-\alpha \sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i^\beta}$$

The log-likelihood is then $$\ell=n\log(\alpha)+n\log(\beta)+(\beta-1)\sum_{i=1}^{n}\log(x_i)-\alpha\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i^\beta$$

The $n$ enters the log-likelihood $\ell$ because of the product over all observations in the original likelihood.

The derivative of the log-likelihood with respect to $\beta$ is

$$\frac{d\ell}{d\beta}=\frac{n}{\beta}+\sum_{i=1}^{n}\log(x_i)-\alpha\sum_{i=1}^{n}\log(x_i)x_i^\beta$$

The $\log$ comes from taking the derivative of $x_i^\beta=e^{\beta\log(x_i)}$ (rewriting $x_i^\beta$ should make it more clear why there's a $\log$ in the derivative).

Comment: Thank you! I'm still not sure why xβi=e^βlog(xi), if there was no log for this part in the log-likelihood function.

Comment: @Max If, as seems very likely, this is homework, your answer is overly detailed; the FAQ suggests "guidance, hints, and useful links"

Comment: @Glen_b I really only gave two pieces of information that OP didn't know. The first is that the likelihood is written as a product over all observations in the data set. The second is that $x_i^\beta=e^{\beta\log(x_i)}$. If a question isn't tagged as such, why should we assume it is a homework problem?

Comment: @metrix $x_i^{\beta}=\left(e^{\log(x_i)}\right)^{\beta}=e^{\beta\log(x_i)}$

Comment: @Max Looks to me like you pretty much did it. And if failing to tag homework as homework is all it takes to get people to do your homework, why would anyone ever use the tag?

Comment: I didn't think tags would be so important. This isn't technically a homework problem that was assigned, just a practice problem from the book that I chose to do.

Comment: @Glen_b That's a fair point. My apologies. I'll keep this in mind for future posts.

Comment: @metrix for coursework - even if not directly assigned - guidance, hints, and pointers to more information are better because you don't really tend to learn it if other people just show you the answer, and the learning is the point, not the getting of answers.